# How can I handle 200K request per sec in wcf

Tags: wcf, windows-services, httpwebrequest

I need to design a system that can handle 200K request per second in each machine over HTTP.
The wcf service need to be hosted under win service.
I wonder if wcf can handle such a requirement?
What is the best system setup/ best configuration?

The machine itself is pretty heavy 32G RAM and 8 core (or more), and can be upgraded if needed

Can I handle such amount of request in each single machine with wcf using http?

Comment: What does your system do when it gets a request?

Comment: Just for comparison, Google is [estimated](http://searchengineland.com/by-the-numbers-twitter-vs-facebook-vs-google-buzz-36709) to deal with 34,000 searches per second. Some rough calculation: On a single machine there are about 60k ports available to make a connection. So you can never have any more than this number of concurrent requests. So if the request takes close to 0.3s to being processed you're maxing out on the number of ports. Honestly, I don't think, you can handle that many requests on a single machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this on a single machine is likely to be pretty tough (if indeed it's possible). It would be better to make your system scale horizontally, so you can add lots of machines as required. How you do that will depend on what your system actually needs to do. If it's some simple calculation which requires no persisted state, it shouldn't be too hard. If you've got some interaction with storage of some form which really needs to be read/written on each request, it'll be a lot harder - and choosing your persistence technology is likely to be pretty key to making it all hang together.

Note that there are other benefits to scaling horizontally too - in particular, the ability to upgrade the system without any downtime (if you're careful) and removing a huge single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some more info on this.

Do you get the request and have to process it immediately?
Can you store the request data and delegate the processing to some other thread/process?  Is there any way to scale the system out instead of up?
Is this in fact the only piece of infrastructure you can deploy stuff to?

I would start by asking what is it that I want to do during request handling. then what the bottlenecks are going to be.